# aix: large files

Tags: nfs, aix, large-files

```
/opt/freeware/bin/ls //media/nfs/slack64/pubblica
/opt/freeware/bin/ls: cannot open directory //media/nfs/slack64/pubblica: Value too large to be stored in data type
```

This happen with coreutils-8.23 from perlz and with 8.24 recompiled on aix
The fs is nfs.
How to solve?

This is the spec of coreutils

```
Summary: The GNU core utilities: a set of tools commonly used in shell scripts
Name:    coreutils
Version: 8.24
Release: 1
License: GPL
Group:   System Environment/Base
URL:     http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/
Source0: ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/%{name}/%{name}-%{version}.tar.gz
Source1: ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/%{name}/%{name}-%{version}.tar.xz.sig
Source2: %{name}-DIR_COLORS
Source3: %{name}-DIR_COLORS.xterm
Source4: %{name}-colorls.sh
Source5: %{name}-colorls.csh
Patch0:  %{name}-%{version}-aix-uname.patch
Patch1:  %{name}-%{version}-aix-configure.patch

BuildRoot: %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-%{release}-root

BuildRequires: gettext, gmp-devel >= 4.3.2
BuildRequires: gcc >= 4.2.3-2
BuildRequires: make

Requires: /sbin/install-info
Requires: info, gettext, gmp >= 4.3.2

Conflicts: mktemp, coreutils-64bit

Provides: fileutils = %{version}-%{release}
Provides: sh-utils = %{version}-%{release}
Provides: stat = %{version}-%{release}
Provides: textutils = %{version}-%{release}
Obsoletes: fileutils <= 4.1.9
Obsoletes: sh-utils <= 2.0.12
Obsoletes: stat <= 3.3
Obsoletes: textutils <= 2.0.21


%description
These are the GNU core utilities.  This package is the combination of
the old GNU fileutils, sh-utils, and textutils packages.

These tools are the GNU versions of common useful and popular file and text
utilities which are used for:
- file management
- shell scripts
- modifying text file (spliting, joining, comparing, modifying, ...)

Most of these programs have significant advantages over their Unix
counterparts, such as greater speed, additional options, and fewer arbitrary
limits.


%prep
%setup -q
%patch0
%patch1


%build
# required if you run 'configure' as root user
export FORCE_UNSAFE_CONFIGURE=1

export CC="gcc -pthread -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGE_FILES"
export CFLAGS="-DSYSV -D_AIX -D_AIX32 -D_AIX41 -D_AIX43 -D_AIX51 -D_ALL_SOURCE -DFUNCPROTO=15 -O -I/opt/freeware/include"
./configure \
    --prefix=%{_prefix} \
    --mandir=%{_mandir} \
    --infodir=%{_infodir} \
    --enable-largefile \
    --enable-nls
gmake %{?_smp_mflags}
gmake


%install
[ "${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}" != "/" ] && rm -rf ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}
gmake DESTDIR=${RPM_BUILD_ROOT} install

bzip2 -9f ChangeLog

(
  cd ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}
  /usr/bin/strip .%{_bindir}/* || :
  gzip --best .%{_infodir}/*info*

  mkdir -p usr/linux/bin
  mkdir -p usr/bin
  cd usr/linux/bin
  ln -sf ../../..%{_bindir}/* .
  cd ../../bin
  for i in dir dircolors vdir tac md5sum pinky seq
  do
     rm ../linux/bin/$i
     ln -sf ../..%{_bindir}/$i .
  done
)

mkdir -p ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}%{_sysconfdir}/profile.d
cp %{SOURCE2} ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}%{_sysconfdir}/DIR_COLORS
cp %{SOURCE3} ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}%{_sysconfdir}/DIR_COLORS.xterm
cp %{SOURCE4} ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}%{_sysconfdir}/profile.d/colorls.sh
cp %{SOURCE5} ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}%{_sysconfdir}/profile.d/colorls.csh
chmod 644 ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}%{_sysconfdir}/DIR*
chmod 644 ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}%{_sysconfdir}/profile.d/*


%pre
# We must deinstall these info files since they're merged in
# coreutils.info. else their postun'll be run too late
# and install-info will fail badly because of duplicates
for file in sh-utils textutils fileutils; do
    /sbin/install-info --delete %{_infodir}/$file.info.gz --dir=%{_infodir}/dir &> /dev/null || :
done


%preun
if [ $1 = 0 ]; then
    /sbin/install-info --delete %{_infodir}/%{name}.info.gz %{_infodir}/dir || :
fi


%post
/usr/bin/grep -v '(sh-utils)\|(fileutils)\|(textutils)' %{_infodir}/dir > \
  %{_infodir}/dir.rpmmodify || exit 0
    /bin/mv -f %{_infodir}/dir.rpmmodify %{_infodir}/dir
/sbin/install-info %{_infodir}/%{name}.info.gz %{_infodir}/dir || :


%clean
[ "${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}" != "/" ] && rm -rf ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}


%files
%defattr(-,root,system,-)
%doc COPYING ABOUT-NLS ChangeLog.bz2 NEWS README THANKS TODO old/*
%config(noreplace) %{_sysconfdir}/DIR_COLORS*
%{_sysconfdir}/profile.d/*
%{_bindir}/*
%{_infodir}/coreutils*
# exclude %{_libdir}/charset.alias as it conflicts with glib2
# %{_libdir}/*
%{_mandir}/man?/*
%{_datadir}/locale/*/*/*
/usr/bin/*
/usr/linux/bin/*
```

Comment: What do you get with `ls -ld` for that directory?

Comment: Are you possibly hitting http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg1IV35122 ?

Comment: Is refer to aix ls located in /usr/bin/ls wich works fine,i want to use the gnu ls for better options(color,etc)

Comment: option #2: [your version of the utilities were not compiled with large file support enabled](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/faq/coreutils-faq.html#Value-too-large-for-defined-data-type)

Comment: read the spec file on first message ./configure \
    --prefix=%{_prefix} \
    --mandir=%{_mandir} \
    --infodir=%{_infodir} \
    --enable-largefile \
    --enable-nls
gmake %{?_smp_mflags}

Comment: did ./configure succeed in enabling large file support? `grep _LARGE_FILES lib/config.h`

Comment: `grep _LARGE_FILES lib/config.h` return ` /* #undef _LARGE_FILES */` is commented,something wrong i think

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Honestly..no,i see ls of aix works,ls of gnu coreutils no,but on hpux and solaris coreutils gnu works fine,probably need a patch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need to ensure that _LARGE_FILES is defined, e.g., try

```
# export CFLAGS="-O3 -D_LARGE_FILES"
```

the `-OX` is optional. I recommend -O3 as a default with gcc and -O2 with xlc

Or, you could try my packaging (coreutils-8.25 at least).

p.s. I just checked perzl site - he is also packaging 8.25 now. The key difference between our packaging methods is that I use installp as package manager and use `/opt/bin` rather than `/opt/freeware/bin` (which means you can have both installed side-by-side and decide which is easier to manage) - Note: as I do not know the convention here I am not (yet) adding an URL to my 'aixtools'. You can try and catch my attention via twitter @rootvgnet if you are interested.

---

As it is too large for a comment - adding - the install instructions should you choose to use my packaging

the install command: -as root- #installp -d /some/dir -agX aixtools.gnu.coreutils; should show in the output a block of info including:

```
SUCCESSES
---------
  Filesets listed in this section passed pre-installation verification
  and will be installed.

  Selected Filesets
  -----------------
  aixtools.gnu.coreutils.rte 8.25.0.0         # built 22-Aug-2016 1702 UTC

  Requisites
  ----------
  (being installed automatically;  required by filesets listed above)
  aixtools.gnu.gettext.rte 0.19.8.1           # built 21-Aug-2016 1821 UTC
  aixtools.gnu.gettext.share 0.19.8.1         # universal files
  aixtools.gnu.libiconv.rte 1.14.0.4          # built 21-Aug-2016 1623 UTC
  aixtools.gnu.libiconv.share 1.14.0.4        # universal files
```

This means than besides coreutils you also need the gnu dependencies 'gettext' for text internationalization, and GNU iconv because coreutils does not accept the way AIX iconv implemented a number of translations.

The respective wiki (because the packages may be updated over time) links are:
 - http://www.aixtools.net/index.php/coreutils
 - http://www.aixtools.net/index.php/gettext
 - http://www.aixtools.net/index.php/libiconv

In short, after downloading the three installp files to (e.g., /tmp/aixtools)

```
# installp -d /tmp/aixtools -agX aixtools.gnu.coreutils
```

This will install the "share" and "rte" components of each, as well as the man pages of coreutils.

If you do not want the man pages use:

```
# installp -u aixtools.gnu.aixtools.man
```

to remove them

Comment: I can try your packagin,where to download,please?

Comment: Thanks for aixtools link,i found on your profile.But is another format or use the standard aix format which I install using installp?

Comment: I have configured with export CFLAGS="-DSYSV -D_AIX -D_AIX32 -D_AIX41 -D_AIX43 -D_AIX51 -D_ALL_SOURCE -DFUNCPROTO=15 -O -I/opt/freeware/include -D_LARGE_FILE
But is the same,with large files give error

Comment: The link to the coreutils page is:http://www.aixtools.net/index.php/coreutils. The download is an installp format, so you can use smitty install_latest to install it. If you add a .I (installp/bff) file to a directory remember to remove .toc (table of contents) so that installp will remake that file (or run inutoc DirName - e.g. inutoc .) I shall try asking and answering a question on HOWTO package OSS for AIX, just not today. p.s. be sure to add /opt/bin to your PATH if you use my packaging. I try very hard to not overwrite existing packaging.

Comment: moderators: I added to the answer - install instructions. This is not directly related to the question - remove if it violates a stackexchange principle. @elbarna - which compiler are you using? FYI: I normally package using xlc.